# App installation date using Flurry Api

Tags: objective-c

I wanted to know is it possible register App installation date using Flurry Api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone doesn't spool up the software when its installed, so no, I don't think you will get that data. The Second time its used, you should receive data on the first time it was run though.